# Jupiter notebook crashes and unable to connect to kernel. Debugging needed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Hi my jyupter notebook was working fine till yesterday. Fro. Today's it is unable to connect to kernel. It's is happening for each and every jyupter notebook. Old project which I have done months ago and new files too. Suggest remedies. I have uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda but of no use. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAtTv.jpg)

Pls suggest remedies

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of text you could have easily pasted and provided as text code to allow those trying to help you easily access the error messages and such. See the bottom section of 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about that.

Comment: ok i will keep it in mind next time. this was my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error report is showing you what the problem is during launch.
The error is being triggered when it hits line 77 of pdb.py.

If you look at [line 77 of the pdb.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f97c8e367869e2aebe9f28bc5f8d4ce36448878/Lib/pdb.py#LL77C1-L77C12), you'll see it reads as the following:

```
import code
```

(By the way, if you scroll up to the top of where I linked, you'll see the pdb is the The Python Debugger)

It looks like you made your on file `code.py` somewhere you shouldn't (i.e., on your current path) and with an syntax error in it and the python debugger tries to run it as part of the launch process and hits the error.
Move that file out of out of `C:\Users\sudis` and try launching again.
Or simply rename it and endeavor to please give your files unique names that don't shadow other major modules in use by Jupyter.

There's a whole write-up on it entitled "Don't break when debugging files with names shadowing standard modules"[here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23615/Dont-break-when-debugging-files-with-names-shadowing-standard-modules) that states:

> "If user has a file which name shadows standard module name (for example, code.py) it breaks debugger:"

Now you now the type of behaviour and error report you'll see when you shadow something that Jupyter relies on to run. It can happen in Python, too, separate from Jupyter. An example is that I think when you using pytest you need to avoid files named `test.py`.

---

By the way, don't feel bad, this is why it is said that one of the hard things in computer science is naming things. See for example [here](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?lang=en)

> "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors." - Jeff Atwood (@codinghorror)

Comment: thank you. it worked. yesterday i installed thonny debugger . and it saved a .py file. it was causing the crash. i am a new to coding and would have never cracked the case without your help.

Comment: how to mark it solved?